# How to add a field validator and set it programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add a field validator, the admin of the website sets the number of characters of a textbox in admin and then... in the front side users can only type upto the number of characters specified by the admin.

In the fron end i aleady pull the number from the database but now i am not sure how to create a validator where i can set the value say:

```
pseudocode

Get the validator
 set the validator to validate these maximum number of characters
     myValidator.setamaxnumber = mydbvalue;
     error message = Only + mydbvalue + charaters are accepted.
```

I hope you understand what i want to do. If not, no need to do a negative vote post your question and i will try my best to supply more information

Thanks a million

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) control like so:

**Markup**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MaxLengthValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**Codebehind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var maxLength = 10;
    MaxLengthValidator.ValidationExpression = @"^[\s\S]{0," + maxLength.ToString() + "}$";
    MaxLengthValidator.ErrorMessage = string.Format("Only {0} charaters are accepted.", maxLength);
}
```